# ASP.NET, MVC, DOJO: RequestError: Unable to load undefined status: 404

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, dojo

I have tried to call ASP.NET MVC Action method from .ASPX page using Dojo. but it is showing the following error..

**RequestError: Unable to load undefined status: 404**

My code is like below:

```
function SearchUser() {
    var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
    var firstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
    var applicationName = document.getElementById("txtApplicationName").value;
    var roleName = document.getElementById("txtRoleName").value;
    var locationType = document.getElementById("txtLocationType").value;
    var location = document.getElementById("txtLocation").value;
    var userType = document.getElementById("txtUserType").value;
    var isAdmin = document.getElementById("chkAdmin").checked;

    var searchUserParameters = { "pageIndex": "1", "pageSize": "100", "userName": ""+ userName +"", "firstName":""+ firstName +"", "lastName":""+ lastName +"", "userType":""+ userType +"", "appName":""+ applicationName +"", "roleName":""+ roleName +"", "LocationType":""+ locationType +"", "location":""+ location +"", "isAdmin":""+ isAdmin +"" };

    var xhrArgs = {
        postData: dojo.toJson(searchUserParameters),
        handleAs: "text",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
        load: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("svsOutput").innerHTML = data;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error occured:" + error);
        }
    }
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
    return false;
}
```

Can anybody suggest me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified a url to post to.

```
var xhrArgs = {
    url: "path/to/service",
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Craig. url is not required for the self page.

Comment: The error message tells me that it is trying to post to 'undefined'.